# Receiving and Displaying data of referenced record in Extbase/Fluid

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase, flexform

**Situation**:

I have an (Extbase/Fluid) extension which stores **a single DB reference** from a specific database table (tt_address).

```xml
<internal_type>db</internal_type>
<allowed>tt_address</allowed>
```

**Intention**:
I want to display data (some db fields) **from this reference** (only) in the frontend.

**Problem**:
How do I get the stored reference in Extbase/Fluid and how do I get access to the data fields? in the frontend?

**Typoscript**:

```js
    tt_content {
      addresscontainer = FLUIDTEMPLATE
      addresscontainer {
    
        templateName = AddressContainer
        templateRootPaths {
          10 = EXT:xyz/Resources/Private/Partials/ContentElements/
        }
        partialRootPaths {
          10 = EXT:xyz/Resources/Private/Partials
        }
        dataProcessing {
          1 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\DatabaseQueryProcessor
          1 {
              options {
                    if.isTrue.field = records
                }
                table = tt_address
                #where = uid = 5
    
                pidInList = 20
                as = address_record
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

**Flexform / XML**:

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes" ?>
    <T3DataStructure>
        <sheets>
            <sDEF>
                <ROOT>
                    <TCEforms>
                        <sheetTitle>TT-Address - Single Address</sheetTitle>
                    </TCEforms>
                    <type>array</type>
                    <el>
                        <faddress>
                            <TCEforms>
                                <label>Single Address</label>
                                <config>
                                    <type>group</type>
                                    <internal_type>db</internal_type>
                                    <allowed>tt_address</allowed>
                                    <size>1</size>
                                    <maxitems>1</maxitems>
                                    <minitems>0</minitems>
                                    <show_thumbs>1</show_thumbs>
                                </config>
                            </TCEforms>
                        </faddress>
                    </el>
                </ROOT>
            </sDEF>
        </sheets>
    </T3DataStructure>
```

**HTML:**

```
<strong>{address_record.data.company}</strong><br>
```

The code is basically working. However, it fetches all records which are stored in the tt_address table. I want the one which was assigend in the backend only.

I hope my intention is clear.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access the FlexForm value from your plugin or content element you can do that with the data type `flexform`:

```
dataProcessing {
  10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\DatabaseQueryProcessor
  10 {
    table = tt_address
    pidInList = 20
    uidInList.data = flexform:pi_flexform:faddress
  }
}
```

See the TypoScript Reference for details on the [data type `flexform`](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/10.4/en-us/DataTypes/Index.html#flexform).

If you're using TYPO3 v11, you can also use the brand new [FlexForm Data Processor](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/11.1/Feature-89509-DataProcessorToResolveFlexFormData.html).